# stdwin is not a tty (mingw64)

Tags: javascript, bash, stdin

I'm trying to learn the basics of STDIN/STDOUT using Node on a Windows10 machine.

Here's my JS file (test.js):

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
    process.stdout.write('chunk:' + chunk.toString());
});

process.stdin.on('end', function () {
    process.stdout.write('end')
});
```

Here's my text file (test.txt)

```
hello
world
again
```

Here is the command I'm running in MINGW64 and the result

```
$ cat test.txt | node test.js
stdin is not a tty
```

I'm new to Bash and STDIN/STDOUT, so please be gentle. :)

Answer (score 0):

Still don't know why GitBash won't work, but I figured out you could get the same work done by using PowerShell.